# How to select questions which have no answers, in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've two classes: Question and Answer. A question may have 0 or many answers.

```
class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = "questions"
    answers = relationship('Answer', backref='question', 
                           primaryjoin="Question.id==Answer.question_id")

class Answer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "answers"
```

Now I want to find all the questions have no answers, how to do it?

I tried:

```
Session.query(Question).filter('count(Question.answers)==0').all()
```

It is incorrect. What is the right one?

Comment: What error message did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
session.query(Question).filter(Question.answers == None).all()
```

which basically is a `NULL` check ([common filter operators](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/ormtutorial.html#common-filter-operators)).

Here's a gist example: http://gist.github.com/560473

The query generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT questions.id AS questions_id 
FROM questions 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM answers 
WHERE questions.id = answers.question_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, use `not exist`:

```
Session.query(Question).filter(not_(exists().where(Answer.question_id==Question.id))).all()
```

Comment: You can have it simpler, although the generated SQL is similar / see my post.